# get value of object using dot . in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Can anyone tell why this is code not working

```
 var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25}; 

 var text = "";
 var x;
 for (x in person) {
   text += person.x + " ";
 }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

If the variable is

```
var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25, x:"male"};
```

and `var x;` is not needed.

then it will work right?

Comment: It's not working, because there's no property named `x` in your object. Use bracket notation instead of dot notation here.

Comment: It should be `person[x]`

Comment: Also: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the key in bracket notation. You could take two versions of a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
object['key'] // bracket notation
object.key    // dot notation
```

Only the first version works with a variable. The value of the variable has to be the wanted key.

```js
var person = { fname: "John", lname: "Doe", age: 25 },
    text = "",
    x;

for (x in person) {
    text += person[x] + " ";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```